# Typescript Generic is not inferring the type

Tags: typescript

I've got a type where I need the part of the array to be generic but whatever I pass in that part of the array, the compiler fails.

```js
export type ErrorFirstArray<Response> = [SanitisedError | null, Response | null | undefined];

export type HandleResponse = <Response>(
  response: AxiosResponse
) => ErrorFirstArray<Response>;

const handleResponse: HandleResponse = () => {
  return [null, 'foo']; // <--- doesn't like the string here
}
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Response | null | undefined'

Is there a better way to define `ErrorFirstArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandleResponse` is a generic function, this means the type parameter is decided by the caller, not the definition. You probably want a generic type, that is a function:

```
export type ErrorFirstArray<Response> = [SanitisedError | null, Response | null | undefined];

export type HandleResponse<Response> = (
  response: AxiosResponse
) => ErrorFirstArray<Response>;

const handleResponse: HandleResponse<string> = () => {
  return [null, 'foo'];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQB7AgZwEoFNOQB2mucAvnAGZQQhwDkAhulvQLABQAJrgMYA2jKKQGNMmOAGVGhYDGAkuAUSg0oiMp1ypIsODACeYUirUAxYFEwxkqxgYA8eAhGK4AfHAC8cANrTZeUVTaDgAHzhCAFd+fgAaOGciEnDImP5UqMIeSmBCXC4AXQBuTi0daHhDYzgACRkuflwk1xInfGSPbzgACk44OGEXNwAuFBYcDtbcTgBKb08QqAsrGztHFrd3Uo5OXlb4AAsGps2SMfrs06m3B2soPIBzTx8e+a9PBH7B3BgoqEIfmisQS9EoEAg9BKnDIQA)

You might find [this](https://youtu.be/kYxhAsIW3NU) video useful for more explanations

Comment: Thanks but if you pass `string` as a generic is states `HandleResponse` is not generic! so confusing

Comment: @rnmalone But that is the point, your `handleResponse` is not generic, it always return a `string`. What os returned is decided by the implementation. A generic function has its type parameter decided by the caller (I could call it like `handleResponse<number>(...)`)

Comment: Thanks mate i just realised my definition for `HandleResponse` is different to the one in your playground.